# Installing Windows Azure Storage v3.0.3 failing using NuGet

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-storage, nuget-package

I am attempting to update my program but installing Windows Azure Storage 3.0.3.0 via NuGet but when I do this I get the following:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.6.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.6.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.6)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client (≥ 5.6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.6.0)'.
Already referencing a newer version of 'Microsoft.Data.OData'.
```

To be honest I think this an issue with the released package as I know it is new.

As anyone seen this before? If so how have you resolved this problem?

I know I could just rollback OData to the version that is supported but wondered if there were other options?

Comment: I just installed it in a project in VS 2013. worked fine.

Comment: @Aravind - I am investigating this as we speak but I am in VS2012 and it is not happy! I am updating an existing project in which I have updated OData to a version other than 5.6.0 which is what is not happy with.

Comment: I see. As it is there is a dependency with the 5.6.0 version. may be you need to downgrade. Looks like this is an existing issue for a while https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/159

Comment: @Aravind - I think the link you have added refers to an issue with an older version for the Windows Azure Storage. I am updating to version 3.0.3.0 and the OData version is 5.6.0. It is looking more and more like I might have to downgrade for the moment.

Comment: What I meant was this issue is ongoing from several older versions. Also this thread about not updating dependencies can help you. https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/436712

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed the exact same problem by downgrading these to 5.6.0:

- Microsoft.Data.OData
- Microsoft.Data.Edm
- System.Spatial

After updating Windows Azure Storage to 3.0.3.0 I was able to re-update them to 5.6.1.

I found this command useful to downgrade:

`uninstall-package <package> -force`

-force will continue regardless of dependencies, but in this case we are adding them back so that should be fine.

Comment: I hit same issue due to having a preview version of azure storage (WindowsAzure.Storage 4.3.2-preview)  uninstalling that along with the ones listed then installing version 4.3.0 sorted it.

Answer (score 11):

From the your comments it looks like they already had a version of Odata greater than 5.6.1 installed in your project.
Therefore:

- Since the dependency graph generated on install would dictate the Odata be 5.6.0
- And the you already has a higher version of Odata installed in your project
- The installation of the package should fail, as we will not downgrade any package during an install-package or update-package

For how to fix this, first make sure you have at least the 2.8 version of NuGet installed.  Then you should use the Package Manager Console and enter:

```
Update-package Microsoft.data.odata –version 5.6.0
```

Then either:

```
Install-package windowsazure.storage –version 3.0.3
```

Or:

```
Update-package windowsazure.storage –version 3.0.3
```

Depending on whether it’s an upgrade or an install of the Windows Azure storage libraries.

Comment: I am running into this issue simply by trying to add Azure Storage nugget package to a project and then trying to execute code. I get the following error: 

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
> in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
> 
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Data.Services.Client is looking for Microsoft.Data.OData version equal to 5.6.0. However as per the dependency of Windows Azure Storage 3.0.3.0 it looks for Microsoft.Data.OData version >= 5.6.0, so latest version of Microsoft.Data.OData gets installed which is higher than 5.6.0.
So while installing Microsoft.Data.Services.Client it finds that there is already higher incompatible version of Microsoft.Data.OData installed and fails to update the nuget package.

Easiest solution to this problem is as below:

**If you are updating the Windows Azure Storage nuget package please follow below steps:**

1. Update the Microsoft.Data.OData version to 5.6.0 using nuget package
   manager command *Update-Package Microsoft.Data.OData -Version 5.6.0*
2. Update the nuget package Windows Azure Storage to 3.0.3.0

**If you are installing the Windows Azure Storage nuget package, follow below steps:**

1. Install the Microsoft.Data.OData version to 5.6.0 using nuget
   package manager command *Install-Package Microsoft.Data.OData
   -Version 5.6.0*
2. Install the nuget package Windows Azure Storage 3.0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Just type in the below command in Package Manager Console.

```
PM> Install-package windowsazure.storage –version 3.0.3
```